# Image Resizing in html and css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

Guys i am learning web development and having problem in making image responsive. Can you please tell me what i should change here

HTML code

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="background: url(assets/img/slide/slide-1.jpg);">
```

CSS

```
#hero {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
        background-color: rgba(39, 37, 34, 0.8);
       overflow: hidden;
       padding: 0;
      }
#hero .carousel-item {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
       background-size: cover;
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
#hero .carousel-item::before {
       content: "";
       background-color: rgba(12, 11, 10, 0.5);
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       left: 0;
       bottom: 0;
     }
#hero .carousel-container {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
     }
```

Comment: Checkout [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) ~ _"Scales the image as large as possible to fill the container, stretching the image if necessary. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains."_

Comment: you didn't even put your html code, #hero doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

You can make your image div resize automatically if you place it in a wrapping div that allows for resizing. Just make sure your image div locks-in the aspect ratio.

**Note:** A scrollbar will appear if your wrapper's aspect ratio does not match the image's aspect ratio.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.resizeable-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: thin dashed red;
  width: 200px; /* Initial size */
}

.banner {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/240/180);
  background-size: cover;
  aspect-ratio: 4 / 3; /* 240/180 = 4/3 */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizeable-container">
  <div class="banner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [link](https://github.com/ArceusDev/henna-design-website) this is the link to my project from where i am learning from. i want these pics in slides to be responsive and when they have to cropped down to fit in a window then they crop from mid having focus point at mid. for example in slide 1 both hands should remain the center of focus. kindly help me sort this out